# Insert values into multiple rows separated by commas

Tags: sql, split, hive, hiveql, explode

I have a table with one column `id`. Now I want to write a hive query that takes an input of comma separated `id` values, split them and insert them row by row. For eg:

Input - `abc,def,ghi`

Output -

```
-----id-----
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: Can you pl share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lateral view [outer]](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView#LanguageManualLateralView-OuterLateralViews) + explode and split:

```
insert into table t2 

select 
       s.id
  from table1 t1 
       lateral view explode (split(t1.id,',')) s as id
```

Demo:

```
select 
       s.id
  from (select 'abc,def,ghi' as id) t1 
       lateral view explode (split(t1.id,',')) s as id
```

Result:

```
id

abc
def
ghi
```

`split(t1.id,',')` produces an array. `explode` - is a table generation function (UDTF), it converts array to rows. A `lateral view` first applies the UDTF to each row of base table and then joins resulting output rows to the input rows.

Comment: where is the insert happening in the above query?

Comment: @AkshatChoudhary Added insert

Comment: could you provide some explanation for the above query?